# Customize ASP.NET Security

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I want to create a separate module for security that deals with creating roles and providing them page wise access and again in that page a granular read, write , view option.. I have been trying it with membership but its not useful. Can anyone suggest me an option or a sample.

Comment: You would do better to say exactly what you were trying to accomplish, and why ASP.NET Membership did not meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use ASP.NET Membership and Role providers? Because these provide a big deal of security instead of using custom code which may introduce security leaks in your application. If you prefer to use a custom authorization module you can add the method protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in your global .asax file. Take a look at:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5353/Custom-Authentication-provider-by-implementing-IHt